# How to reference one model id to another model in Java (Spring Boot)?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, relationship

I have 2 models: Order and User. There are id, orderDate, totalPrice, totalDiscount, price and **userId** in Order model. I want to reference **id** from **User** to **userId** to **Order**. How can I do this with using Spring Boot, Spring Data Jpa and Hibernate? Then I use MySQL workbench.

Technologies which I used: Spring Boot, Spring Data Jpa, Hibernate, MySQL, Liquebase, Lombok, ModelMapper and Spring Boot Validation.

```html
Order.java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="orders")
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    @ApiModelProperty(required = true, example = "2021-08-20T00:00:00")
    @NotNull(message = "Created date cannot be null")
    private LocalDateTime orderDate;

    @NotNull(message = "Total price cannot be null")
    private BigDecimal totalPrice;

    @NotNull(message = "Total discount cannot be null")
    private BigDecimal totalDiscount;

    @NotNull(message = "Price cannot be null")
    private BigDecimal price;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName = "id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
//    @NotNull(message = "User ID cannot be null")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id")
    private List<OrderProduct> orderProducts;
}


User.java
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Name cannot be blank")
    private String name;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email cannot be blank")
    @Email(message = "Email should be valid")
    private String email;

    @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "Password should have at least 8 characters")
    private String password;

    @NotNull(message = "Password cannot be null")
    @Size(min = 8, message = "Password should have at least 8 characters")
    private String confirmPassword;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "id") // mappedBy added: 04.01.2022
    @JoinColumn(name="order_id", nullable = false)
    private List<Order> orders;
}
```